# df ['X'].unique() and TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

all,

I have a column in  a dataframe that looks like this:

```
allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed']
Out[419]: 
78         ML
81       CITI
92         ML
173      CITI
235        ML
262        ML
264        ML
25617      GS
25621    CITI
25644    CITI
25723      GS
25778    CITI
25786    CITI
25793      GS
25797    CITI
Name: BrokerMixed, Length: 2554, dtype: object
```

Although the column is an object. I am not able to group by that column or even extract the unique values of that column. For example when I do:

```
allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed'].unique()
```

I get an error

```
     uniques = table.unique(values)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1340, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I also get an error when I do group by.

Any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: You have on cell contain np.array

Comment: Can you please show a short sample of your overall dataframe where you have "BrokerMixed" column?

Comment: can you show the output for `print allHoldingsFund.loc[78, 'BrokerMixed']`

Comment: @Sahil   `allHoldingsFund.loc[78, 'BrokerMixed']
Out[422]: 
array('ML',
      dtype='<U2')`

Comment: @user2906838   It is quite large

Comment: Try now `print allHoldingsFund.loc[78, 'BrokerMixed'][0]` and`print type(allHoldingsFund.loc[78, 'BrokerMixed'][0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest you to check what's `type` of your `column`. You may try as follows

```
print (type(allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed']))
```

If this is a `dataframe series`, you may try

```
allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed'].reset_index()['BrokerMixed'].unique()
```

and check if this works for you.

`EDIT 2020` : Your way to get unique and mentioned answers fetch same results using Python 3

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harry_pb `type(allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed'])
Out[423]: pandas.core.series.Series
`     your code `allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed'].reset_index()['BrokerMixed'].unique()` gives  an error.   how can I get rid of the array and make the whole column an object  please?

Answer (score 5):

You have an array in your data column, you could try the following

```
allHoldingsFund['BrokerMixed'].apply(lambda x: str(x)).unique()
```

Comment: what do you get as the error ?. Can you answer my comment on your question.

Comment: `File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1340, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: error `AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'unique'
`

Comment: I can only suggest that you look at the variable `a=allHoldingsFund.loc[78, 'BrokerMixed']` and try to convert it into a string, then apply the function to your column and take the unique value.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have a NumPy array in your series. But you can't hash NumPy arrays and `pd.Series.unique`, like `set`, relies on hashing.

If you can't ensure your series data only consists of strings, you can convert NumPy arrays to tuples before calling `pd.Series.unique`:

```
s = pd.Series([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1, 'hello', 'test', 1, 'test'])

def tuplizer(x):
    return tuple(x) if isinstance(x, (np.ndarray, list)) else x

res = s.apply(tuplizer).unique()

print(res)

array([(1, 2, 3), 1, 'hello', 'test'], dtype=object)
```

Of course, this means your data type information is lost in the result, but at least you get to see your "unique" NumPy arrays, provided they are 1-dimensional.

Comment: thanks jpp   i think i ll do some code change to make sure the column is only object as opposed to a mix of object and array

Comment: @SBad arrays *are objects*